# Configuring @testing-library/react with Vite test

Tags: reactjs, testing, vite

Project recently migrated from Jest to Vite but I am struggling with getting the global configuration working for react testing library.

When using jest we had an override for the testIdAttribute which looked like this

```
setupFile.ts

import '@testing-library/jest-dom'
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect'
import { configure } from '@testing-library/dom'

// react-testing-library defaults to testIdAttribute of data-testid
// override this to be consistent with our cypress tests
configure({
  testIdAttribute: 'data-test-id'
})
```

Here in the new setup with Vite

```
vite-config.ts

import { configDefaults, defineConfig } from 'vitest/config'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  test: {
    globals: true,
    environment: 'jsdom',
    css: true,
    setupFiles: ['./tests/vite-setup.ts'],
    includeSource: ['src/**/*.{js,ts}'],
    exclude: [...configDefaults.exclude]
  }
})
```

```
vite-setup.ts

import { afterEach, beforeEach, expect, vi } from 'vitest'
import { cleanup, configure } from '@testing-library/react'
import matchers from '@testing-library/jest-dom/matchers'


expect.extend(matchers)

configure({
  testIdAttribute: 'data-test-id'
}) <- not working

afterEach(() => {
  cleanup()
})

beforeEach(() => {
  ...

})
```

I have tried using the configure function within the individual tests themselves & this doesn't work either.

Comment: Hi all figured out the issue.I needed a line in my setup file `import '@testing-library/jest-dom/vitest'`

Secondly I needed to update to latest the `@testing-library/jest-dom` package.

Thirdly I need to comment out the import of `'@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect'` from my original setupFile.ts (used for Jest) as it was conflicting with my new vite setupfile